# Unable to capture MQTT log callback

Tags: callback, mqtt

I am having trouble getting the on_log callback to trigger.  I have used it on other programs w/o problems but this one is being difficult.  I have included the relevant code snippets (I hope!).  All other call backs are working fine.  This program isn't threaded (except MQTT.start) so there aren't any other actions.  Any suggestions where to look would be appreciated.  fwiw, the problem I'm trying to track down is that MQTT stops responding after a few hours.  The MQTT server is on a separate server, is used by numerous other processes and has no known issues.

```
    # Set up MQTT - wait until we have an ipaddr so we know the network has been started
    logger.debug("Waiting for ip address to be assigned")
    while True:
        ipaddr = get_local_IP()
        if ipaddr is not None:
            logger.info('IP address is {}'.format(ipaddr))
            break
        sleep(2.0)
    logger.debug("Waiting for MQTT broker connection")
    mqttc = mqtt.Client()
    mqttc.on_message = on_message
    mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
    mqttc.on_publish = on_publish
    mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
    while True:
        try:
            mqttc.connect("192.168.0.18", 1884, 30)
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ENETUNREACH:
                raise
            logger.warning('Network error - retrying')
            sleep(15)
            continue
        logger.debug('Connect initiated without error')
        break
    mqttc.loop_start()
    mqttc.on_log = on_log
    while not MQ_link:
        sleep(1)
```

```
def on_connect(mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
    global MQ_link
    logger.debug("Connected: rc = " + str(rc))
    if rc == 0:
        MQ_link = True
```

```
def on_log(mqttc, obj, level, string):
    verb = string.split('(').strip()
    if verb[0] not in ['Sending PINGREQ', 'Received PINGRESP']:
        logger.debug('LOG: ' + string)
```

Comment: Any reason you are not setting the `on_log` callback before connecting along with all the other callbacks? And are you sure you are actually getting the `mqttc.loop_start()` command?

Comment: I had it with the others first - didn’t work there either.  MQTT start does start the MQTT thread since all other MQTT commands work.  It is just the on_log which appears to be ignored.